# wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4 (with patched qt) Characters broken and svg font converted to image

Tags: pdf, fonts, wkhtmltopdf

sorry for another wkhtmltopdf font topic. 
I´m trying to convert a HTML page which uses a custom font by use of wkthmltopdf:

```
exec('/home/camelot/bin/wkhtmltopdf --orientation portrait --encoding utf-8 --page-size A4 --disable-smart-shrinking -T 0 -B 0 -L 0 -R 0 bill.html bill6.pdf ');

...

@font-face {
      font-family: 'camelot';
      src: url('gbcamweba-webfont.eot');
      src: url('gbcamweba-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
           url('gbcamweba-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
           url('gbcamweba-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
           url('gbcamweba-webfont.svg#camelotregular') format('svg');
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
    }
```

Unfortunately some characters are broken in resulting PDF: [image]

I´ve recognized when only using the svg version of my custom font the shapes are rendered correctly but also the type gets converted to an image.

Does one know if I can use an SVG font without converting it to an image **OR** how to accomplish correct font rendering?

- wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4
- centos 6.9
- tried as base64 encoded type
- tried to install the fonts in centos
- tried older versions 0.9 and 0.10 ...

Answer (score 2):

This is how it solved it for me:

Use only OTF format no matter if the font gets installed in centos OR loaded by font-face. With otf the font is displayed correctly and stays type.

Comment: THIS WORKED! I wish I could pay you a beer ;) Also, previously I had identified the problem is resolved by using a version linked against QT5, and not QT4, but this wasn't an option in our production environment.

Comment: For me a similar solution worked: just try different fonts present on the (Windows) system, although they seem not to be in OTF format.